# Updating to MySQL 8.0 created issue when deleting item referenced by other table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints, mysql-8.0

After the upgrade to MySQL 8.0, I encountered the following problem:

I have two tables, let's call them A and B. B has a column reference for table A and a constraint (foreign key) set so that when deleting the referenced object, the value is set to null (ON DELETE SET NULL).

```
 /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
 /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
 /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
 /*!40101 SET NAMES UTF8 */;
 /*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
 /*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
 /*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
 /*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
 /*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
 /*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

 CREATE TABLE `A` (
 `ID` VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE UTF8_BIN NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
 ) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;

 CREATE TABLE `B` (
   `ID` VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE UTF8_BIN 
    DEFAULT NULL,
   `COL_B` VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE UTF8_BIN 
    DEFAULT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `B_FK5` FOREIGN KEY (`COL_B`) REFERENCES `A` (`ID`) 
 ON 
    DELETE SET NULL
 ) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;

 INSERT INTO `A` (`ID`) VALUES ('1');

 INSERT INTO `B` (`ID`,`COL_B`) VALUES ('1','1');

 DELETE FROM A;

 SELECT * FROM B;
```

Problem: When deleting an item from table A, the reference in table B is not set to null (the key remains although the object with that key was deleted).

Extra info: Up until now I used MySql 5.7 and didn't have this problem. After switching to MySql 8.0.15 I started to see this behaviour. Furthermore, this problem occurs only on local and CD machines and doesn't reproduce on cloud machines. As an impact, some tests started to fail when running CD jobs.

Another strange thing is that right before deleting the item, if a modification is made in table A (switch order of columns), the issue doesn't reproduce.

I've also tried to use a MySQL run on Docker and the issue is the same. Really, this is a blocking issue and the fact that it happens only in this case makes it more difficult to understand. From MySQL logs I couldn't get squat.

Any clue that could help with this investigation?

LATER EDIT: The constraint is correctly defined, it worked correctly up until now

Comment: Great question, and maybe you have discovered some sort of bug in MySQL 8.  If you can't get your problem resolved here, try posting directly to the MySQL forums.

Comment: No, the constraint is correct. It worked like this for MySql 5.7

Comment: can compare between the two versions

Comment: [It's working as expected.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8QfH6uT5WUhHVXpkDSHsXL/1) My guess is, that your scenario is different from what you show in the question.

Comment: @DanFromGermany yes there is a difference, the meta data, but I tried with these tables and it is reproducible. I will update the metadata as well

Comment: It still works as expected. I still guess your scenario is different. Maybe you have some strange server configuration. The foreign key feature is so fundamental in MySQL, I doubt it's buggy at all.

Comment: @DanFromGermany I reproduced the issue also with the script below. Be sure to have MySQL 8.0.15

Answer (score 2):

I managed to reproduce it with the following script that contains only 2 tables, both on a MySQL 8.0.15 standalone installation and by using Docker. Both were performed on MacOS.

This is the command for running MySQL 8.0.15 on Docker:

```
docker run -p 3306:3306 --restart=always --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=somepassword -d mysql:8.0.15 mysqld --default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password --sql-mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES"
```

This is the SQL script:

```
create schema test;
use test;

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES UTF8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `EMPLOYEES`;
/*!40101 SET @SAVED_CS_CLIENT     = @@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT = UTF8 */;
CREATE TABLE `EMPLOYEES` (
    `KEY` VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE UTF8_BIN NOT NULL,
    `PROFILEIMAGEKEY1` VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE UTF8_BIN,
    PRIMARY KEY (`KEY`),
    CONSTRAINT `EMPLOYEE_FK1` FOREIGN KEY (`PROFILEIMAGEKEY1`) REFERENCES `PICTURES` (`KEY`) ON DELETE SET NULL
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT = @SAVED_CS_CLIENT */;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `PICTURES`;
/*!40101 SET @SAVED_CS_CLIENT     = @@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT = UTF8 */;
CREATE TABLE `PICTURES` (
  `KEY` VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE UTF8_BIN NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`KEY`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT = @SAVED_CS_CLIENT */;

/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

INSERT INTO `PICTURES` (`KEY`) VALUES ('1');

INSERT INTO `EMPLOYEES` (`KEY`,`PROFILEIMAGEKEY1`) VALUES ('abc', '1');
select * from `PICTURES`;
SELECT * FROM `EMPLOYEES`;
DELETE FROM `PICTURES`;

SELECT * FROM `EMPLOYEES`;
```

Please note that this script works fine on MySQL 5.7.x (standalone installation or Docker).

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=94400) that we fixed in 8.0.16. I just tested your script on 8.0.15 and 8.0.16. I was able to reproduce the problem in 8.0.15 and indeed, in 8.0.16 (next release), the problem is gone.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sounds great, then I look forward to the release of 8.0.16